# Java - Setting ResourceBundle Values at Runtime

Tags: java, locale, resourcebundle

I have an application that is handed some xml, part of which looks like this:

```
<resource name='Do this thing">
  <attribute name="name" type="string" xml:Lang="ar" value="Do that thing in ar"/>
  <attribute name="name" type="string" xml:Lang="fr" value="Do that thing in fr"/>
  <attribute name="name" type="string" xml:Lang="fr-CA" value="Do that thing in fr-    CA"/>
</resource>
```

Though of course there are 25 languages instead of three.  We then use this xml to build a dialog we present to our users which contains the translated version of 'Do this thing.'  I thought that this would be as straight forward as parsing the xml and building a ResourceBundle  and then using that to get the translation based on current Locale.  But it looks like it's not possible to set the ResourceBundle contents at runtime.  Or at least I can't figure out how to do it.  Am I missing something or can someone suggest an alternative besides just comparing the langauge / country codes myself?

Thanks!

Comment: No. ResourceBundle already has its own scheme for handling locales, via bundles with the locale as the end of the name.

Comment: Right.  I was trying to leverage that.  Creating the appropriately named ResourceBundles in code works fine.  The problem is that the contents seem to have to be fixed at compile time.

Comment: At class load time.